# django:how to show StreamingHttpRespomse as a video?

Tags: python, django, streaming

My django project returns an HttpStreamingRespons that contains frames of a video:

views.py

```
@condition(etag_func=None)
def broadcast(request):
    global current_user_cam
    cc = current_vudeo.update()
    print(type(cc))
    resp = HttpResponse(cc)
    return render(rtsp)
```

current_video.update()

```
def update():
    while True:
        yield(b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' +
            bytearray(self.frame) + b'\r\n')
```

The response is generating, but how can I post this generated result in an HTML template ?

Comment: return HttpResponse("<h1>You can directly render html string in response<h1>").

Comment: @SivaSankar this is not working.

Comment: do you want to display text?

Comment: @SivaSankar no, images.  The stream is a continues video frames

Comment: this would help i think, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49621370/11282077

Comment: @SivaSankar thanks for the link; but that method didn't work also. for the record the output of the update function is the yield of <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15832328/11282077 - how to display image in django httpresponse.

Comment: this produces: "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not generator"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208849/python-django-streaming-video-mp4-file-using-httpresponse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227896/discussion-between-siva-sankar-and-mohammed-baashar).