# Streaming video to browser in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, video-streaming

I have a python script that create frames from an UDP source (the source send a custom packet containing one row of the frame). After getting a full frame (640x480) I would like to send it to the browser (I should send at least 25fps).

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't need to buffer images you can [use motion JPEG with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197638/create-a-mjpeg-stream-from-jpeg-images-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

from my experience one of the quickest way to setup is using flask with cv2 to stream frames to the browser you can follow this [tutorial](https://pyimagesearch.com/2019/09/02/opencv-stream-video-to-web-browser-html-page/)