# How to stream output from camera to webview video element on Android

Tags: android, webview, video-streaming

**Info:**
I have an external camera connected to my Android device (media player) using USB.
And I can read an output from the camera and I receive the `ByteArray` with the data.

**Question:**
Now I'd like to display that stream (`ByteArray` buffer) in the `WebView` using the `<video>` element. The reason for that is that I have a web application running in that webview and I want to integrate camera preview into it. But displaying the camera output in some `TextureView` (or any other Android) native frame on top of the webview will be very limiting for integrating the entire user experience together.

What's the best approach to implement this?

- Intercepting the requests? But that only works with files right? How do I supply the stream instead
- I was hoping I could somehow have the `<video>` element stream from the `m3u8` source which will be provided from the device itself... just don't know how to do that.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to stream video with `mjpeg` format.

It's basically a sequence of JPEG or PNG images served within a single HTTP request. It has it's own MIME type and can be displayed on the web page by just adding `<img src="your_stream.mjpeg">`.

To serve this kind of stream you start an http server and write a handler. It should receive client connection, dump MJPEG-specific header to it and then push images one by one. I didn't find good example for Android, but you can find an example for python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21197851/4755595).

Mjpeg might be good for your case as it's very simple and you can get away without external dependencies. If your camera returns PNG or JPEG by default it's even better as you don't need to do any encoding which might be resource-intensive. Though it has some issues: video latency might be unpredictable and accumulate over time.

The other way is to use media framework like GStreamer. It's a popular one and has its port to Android.

Using it you can start a thread that will read data directly from your camera and then convert it to any format your browser can understand.

Formats to consider:

- it can serve `mjpeg` so you don't have to write your own server
- `hls` (or `dash` as an alternative), which is m3u8 you mentioned. Video is split into chunks and written to filesystem; then you can serve it via http locally and play in browser using library like `hls.js`. Good thing is that resulting stream is seekable; bad thing is that latency usually >1 sec
- `webrtc` is the most advanced way, use it if you need sub-second latency

One more simple way would be to just send images as byte array via websocket and display them in `<img>` tag [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20756091/4755595) as soon as they arrive.